# User sign up and login, storing database and querying for username and password using SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am a newbie in Android. So my application requires a user access, So I have already set up the layout files.

I have created the Database Schema, created an class that extends SQliteOpenHelper, assigned the contentValues,and also I have also made a query to retrieve the username and password.

Logging the messages The database gets created, the new rows are also inserted into the database but when I use the query to fetch the user in login screen its malfunctioning.

So to sum it up my query is troubling me.

**SQliteOpenHeler Class**

```
package com.example.andorid.ersnexus.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


import com.example.andorid.ersnexus.Message;
import com.example.andorid.ersnexus.database.UserDbSchema.UserTable;


public class UserBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userBase.db";


private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
private Context context;

public UserBaseHelper (Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    Message.message("Constructor Called", context);
}


@Override
public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + UserTable.NAME + "(" +
            " _id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            UserTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
            UserTable.Cols.ENROLLMENT_NUMBER + ", " +
            UserTable.Cols.USER_NAME + ", " +
            UserTable.Cols.FULL_NAME + ", " +
            UserTable.Cols.PASSWORD + ", " +
            UserTable.Cols.EMAIL + "," +
            UserTable.Cols.DATE_OF_BIRTH +
            ")"
    );
    Message.message("onCreate() called", context);

}


public String fetchUser (String userName) {

    mDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();


    UserCursorWrapper c = queryCrimes(new String[]{UserTable.Cols.USER_NAME, UserTable.Cols.PASSWORD},
            UserTable.Cols.USER_NAME + " = ?", new String[]{userName});


    String uname,pass;
    pass = "not found";
    try {
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            uname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UserTable.Cols.USER_NAME));
            if(uname.equals(userName)){
                pass = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UserTable.Cols.PASSWORD));
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }finally{
        c.close();
    }
    return pass;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + UserTable.NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    Message.message("Database Upgraded", context);
    this.onCreate(db);

}

private UserCursorWrapper queryCrimes (String[] projection, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
            UserTable.NAME,
            projection,//Columns - null select columns
            whereClause,
            whereArgs,
            null,//groupBy
            null,//having
            null //orderBy
    );
    return new UserCursorWrapper(cursor);
}


}
```

*The Working*

When the user hits Submit button in sign up activity the contentValues are stored using a method addUser(UserData userdata)

```
public void addUser (UserData userData) {

    ContentValues values = getContentValues(userData);
    mDatabase.insert(UserTable.NAME, null, values);
    Message.message("Row inserted",mContext);


}

public static ContentValues getContentValues (UserData userData) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(UserTable.Cols.UUID, userData.getId().toString());
    values.put(UserTable.Cols.ENROLLMENT_NUMBER, userData.getEnrollmentNumber());
    values.put(UserTable.Cols.USER_NAME, userData.getUserName());
    values.put(UserTable.Cols.FULL_NAME, userData.getFullName());
    values.put(UserTable.Cols.PASSWORD, userData.getPassword());
    values.put(UserTable.Cols.EMAIL, userData.getEmail());
    values.put(UserTable.Cols.DATE_OF_BIRTH, userData.getDob().toString());

    return values;
    }
```

Now in the login activity when the user hits login button the following query is used

```
public String fetchUser (String userName) {

    mDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();


    UserCursorWrapper c = queryCrimes(new String[]{UserTable.Cols.USER_NAME, UserTable.Cols.PASSWORD},
            UserTable.Cols.USER_NAME + " = ?", new String[]{userName});


    String uname,pass;
    pass = "not found";
    try {
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            uname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UserTable.Cols.USER_NAME));
            if(uname.equals(userName)){
                pass = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(UserTable.Cols.PASSWORD));
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }finally{
        c.close();
    }
    return pass;
}

private UserCursorWrapper queryCrimes (String[] projection, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
            UserTable.NAME,
            projection,//Columns - null select columns
            whereClause,
            whereArgs,
            null,//groupBy
            null,//having
            null //orderBy
    );
    return new UserCursorWrapper(cursor);
}
```

And here is what it takes in the login activity to get the username from fetchUser(userName) method

```
package com.example.andorid.ersnexus;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.andorid.ersnexus.database.UserBaseHelper;





public class UserLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mUserName;
private EditText mUserPassword;
private Button mLoginButton;
private Button mSignUpButton;
private UserBaseHelper mHelper;
private String userName;
private String pass;
private String password;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_user_login);

    mHelper = new UserBaseHelper(this);


    //user UserName editText in fragment_user_login
    mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_user_name);



    //PASSWORD editText
    mUserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_user_pass);




    //SignUp button
    mSignUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this, UserSignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });



    //Login Button
    mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            userName = mUserName.getText().toString();
            pass = mUserPassword.getText().toString();
            password = mHelper.fetchUser(userName);

            if (pass.equals(password)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this, UserProfileActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("username", userName);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this, "Wrong Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_textView);
                textView.setText(password);
            }

        }
    });
}

}
```

**UserSignUpActivity**

```
package com.example.andorid.ersnexus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.andorid.ersnexus.database.UserBaseHelper;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class UserSignUpFragment extends Fragment {


private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;
private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "dialog_date";
private EditText mErNo1;
private EditText mErNo2;
private EditText mErNo3;
private EditText mErNo4;
private EditText mErNo5;
private EditText mErNo6;
private EditText mErNo7;
private EditText mErNo8;
private EditText mErNo9;
private EditText mErNo10;
private EditText mErNo11;
private EditText mErNo12;
private EditText mUserName;
private EditText mFullName;
private EditText mPassword;
private EditText mEmail;
private EditText mConfirmPassword;
private Button mDob;
private Button mSubmit;
private UserData mUserData;
private String erNo1;
private String erNo2;
private String erNo3;
private String erNo4;
private String erNo5;
private String erNo6;
private String erNo7;
private String erNo8;
private String erNo9;
private String erNo10;
private String erNo11;
private String erNo12;
private UserBaseHelper mHelper;

DateFormat formatDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance();


@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUserData = new UserData();
    mHelper = new UserBaseHelper(getActivity());
}


public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_sign_up, container, false);


    //enrollmentNumber of user


    mErNo1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_1);
    mErNo1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo1(s.toString());
            if (mErNo1.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo2.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo1 = mErNo1.getText().toString();

    mErNo2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_2);
    mErNo2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo2(s.toString());
            if (mErNo2.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo3.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo2 = mErNo2.getText().toString();

    mErNo3 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_3);
    mErNo3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo3(s.toString());
            if (mErNo3.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo4.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo3 = mErNo3.getText().toString();

    mErNo4 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_4);
    mErNo4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo4(s.toString());
            if (mErNo4.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo5.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
     erNo4 = mErNo4.getText().toString();


    mErNo5 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_5);
    mErNo5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo5(s.toString());
            if (mErNo5.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo6.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo5 = mErNo5.getText().toString();


    mErNo6 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_6);
    mErNo6.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo6(s.toString());
            if (mErNo6.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo7.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo6 = mErNo6.getText().toString();


    mErNo7 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_7);
    mErNo7.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo7(s.toString());
            if (mErNo7.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo8.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo7 = mErNo7.getText().toString();


    mErNo8 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_8);
    mErNo8.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo8(s.toString());
            if (mErNo8.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo9.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo8 = mErNo8.getText().toString();

    mErNo9 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_9);
    mErNo9.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo9(s.toString());
            if (mErNo9.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo10.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo9 = mErNo9.getText().toString();


    mErNo10 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_10);
    mErNo10.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo10(s.toString());
            if (mErNo10.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo11.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo10 = mErNo10.getText().toString();


    mErNo11 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_11);
    mErNo11.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo11(s.toString());
            if (mErNo11.getText().length() == 1) {
                mErNo12.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo11 = mErNo11.getText().toString();


    mErNo12 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.erno_12);
    mErNo12.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setErNo12(s.toString());
            if (mErNo12.getText().length() == 1) {
                mUserName.requestFocus();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    erNo12 = mErNo12.getText().toString();


    //USER_NAME editText field in fragment_user_sign_up
    mUserName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.userName_editText);
    mUserName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setUserName(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    final String userName = mUserName.getText().toString();


    //FULL_NAME editText field in fragment_user_sign_up
    mFullName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.fullName_editText);
    mFullName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setFullName(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    final String fullName = mFullName.getText().toString();


    //PASSWORD editText field in fragment_user_sign_up
    mPassword = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.passwd_editText);
    mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setPassword(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    final String pass = mPassword.getText().toString();


    //confirmPassword editText field in fragment_user_sign_up
    mConfirmPassword = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.confirm_passwd_editText);
    mConfirmPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setCorrectPassword(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });
    final String cPass = mConfirmPassword.getText().toString();


    //EMAIL Id of user
    mEmail = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.emai_id_editText);
    mEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mUserData.setEmail(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
    });


    //datOFBirth button
    mDob = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dob_button);
    updateDate();
    mDob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mUserData.getDob());
            dialog.setTargetFragment(UserSignUpFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
            dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_DATE);
        }
    });


    //submit button
    mSubmit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {

            if (mUserName.length() == 0) {
                createToast("Enter UserName");
            } else if (mFullName.length() == 0) {
                createToast("Enter FullName");
            } else if (mPassword.length() == 0) {
                createToast("Enter Password");
            } else if (!mUserData.getPassword().equals(mUserData.getCorrectPassword())) {
                createToast("Password And Confirm PassWord does not match");
            } else if (mErNo1.length() == 0 &&
                    mErNo2.length() == 0  &&
                    mErNo3.length() == 0  &&
                    mErNo4.length() == 0  &&
                    mErNo5.length() == 0  &&
                    mErNo6.length() == 0  &&
                    mErNo7.length() == 0  &&
                    mErNo8.length() == 0  &&
                    mErNo9.length() == 0  &&
                    mErNo10.length() == 0  &&
                    mErNo11.length() == 0  &&
                    mErNo12.length() == 0 ) {
                createToast("Enter Enrollment Number");
            }
            else {
                //Intent i = UserProfileActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mUserData.getUserName(), mUserData.getFullName(), fetchEnrollmentNumber());
               // startActivity(i);


                try{
                    Message.message("Database Created",getActivity());
                    createNewUser();
                }catch (SQLException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "DATABASE NOT SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }


        }
    });


    return v;
}

public void createToast (String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public String fetchEnrollmentNumber () {
    String ErNo = mUserData.getErNo1() +
            mUserData.getErNo2() +
            mUserData.getErNo3() +
            mUserData.getErNo4() +
            mUserData.getErNo5() +
            mUserData.getErNo6() +
            mUserData.getErNo7() +
            mUserData.getErNo8() +
            mUserData.getErNo9() +
            mUserData.getErNo10() +
            mUserData.getErNo11() +
            mUserData.getErNo12();

    mUserData.setEnrollmentNumber(ErNo);

    return mUserData.getEnrollmentNumber();
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE ) {
        Date date = (Date) data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        mUserData.setDob(date);
        updateDate();
    }
}

private void updateDate () {
    mDob.setText(formatDate.format(mUserData.getDob()));

}

public void createNewUser(){


    mUserData.getUserName();
    mUserData.getPassword();
    UserLab.get(getActivity()).addUser(mUserData);
}
```

}

So I would appreciate some help or some other way around to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've gotten the text from the EditText immediately when the view is created.

```
//user UserName editText in fragment_user_login
mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_user_name);
userName = mUserName.getText().toString();

//PASSWORD editText
mUserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_user_pass);
pass = mUserPassword.getText().toString();
```

Both the strings are empty.

You should instead only find the views, then when you click on the button, get the texts.

Also move this into the button click

```
password = mHelper.fetchUser(userName);
```

---

Also, storing plaintext passwords is rule #1 not to do in password management, but that's outside the scope of the question

Comment: SO i have did as you said,but still does not work,also i have edited my post as per your requirement.I also marked one thing in my phone the onCreate database was called when i used the submit button in the signup activity file but in emulator constructor method of SQLiteOpenHelper Class was called twice.I dont know if this helps though

Comment: Are you sure that rows are really being inserted? Your code isn't checking that, it's only logging the message that rows are inserted. If you are certain that they are, you can log the username and password within the onClick (and the database action) to verify the data is what you expect.

Comment: I actually cant access the database using android monitor the /data is not opening And the content values i passed i tested them using an intent from the signup activity to direct userprofile activity so those getter and setter are not at all null for that I am sure.

Comment: You can debug your database by seeing that the `mDatabase.insert` call returns the number of inserted rows (I think). You could also try adding Stetho while you debug.  http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Comment: yes sir you were right those values were empty i updated my post with the userSignupfragment,and i know it would a silly mistake of mine that gives a null value

Comment: Okay found my mistake i updated it. Thank you so so much sir. It feels so good to solve an error. I appreciate your help sir thanks again. Have a nice Day

Comment: That's a really long activity, but again, and cannot do `getText().toString()`  immediately within onCreate. All those string values will be empty. You have attached a bunch of TextWatchers for really no obvious reason. You could extract the fields you need after you click the button. Similarly, calling `userData.getUserName();` on its own does nothing, and you added a blank `new UserData();` instead of using `mUserData` why??

Comment: yes I realized about using mUserData thats why i marked it as solved.And I have added those textWatchers for future purpose.And yea my activity is long because i have an enrollment number having 12 digits , and i am coding so that i can take values from each value of enrollment number and use them for later purpose.And thx for the tips sir. And humans tend to make errors and thats what we learn from,but you were a great help :).Oh and i would also up ur answer but cant low experience lol xD.

Comment: Thats fine. You may want to look into the databinding library. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html